# Is there a way to get rid of the center dot when transforming?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

I'm trying to figure out how to disable the center mark thingy when transforming objects in photoshop.

I always end up dragging the dot instead of the object and it gets pretty annoying.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to disable the transformation center, just hide it.

- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> Win to activate the transform frame
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> Win to hide the transform frame but keeping it active